# swift3 country and phone code Picker

Tags: swift3, pickerview

I am using Xcode Version 8.3.3, trying to use country pickerview from https://github.com/4taras4/CountryCode. I manually just drag and drop CountryPicker folder to my xcode project. However, i got error when import CountryPicker (error is "No such module 'CountryPicker'")
Is anyone can help to solve it and teach me how to start using it?

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import CountryPicker

class ViewController: UIViewController, , CountryPickerDelegate {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!


target 'YourTArgetNAme' do
  pod 'CountryPickerSwift', '1.4.4'
end
```

try installing it as a pod

Comment: after pod install, it ask me to convert syntax and then it comes a lot of error

Comment: use this version , is for swift 3.  pod 'CountryPickerSwift', '1.4.4'

Comment: try adding your dragged framework in embed biinary in project settings